# Edge Developer Tools, data fetch not appearing in Network pane

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

Have a look at the page at the following URL in MS Edge developer tools. 
https://quotes.wsj.com/bond/BX/TMUBMUSD10Y

The large quote under the heading "YIELD" on the left side of the screen updates periodically, and I am trying to intercept the request to a web server that downloads data to update the quote on the screen. I want to see the URL, headers, and response of that request. I have the Network tab selected in the middle pane, session profiling turned on, and "All" selected for content type. When the quote on the page updates to a new number, I do not see any activity in the Network pane. No GET or POST event appears. There is an event labeled "TMUBMUSD10Y" for the initial loading of the page, but that does not repeat when the quote is updated. There has to be a way to intercept the fetch of data that updates the quote, but I don't see it.

Comment: Any reason you labeled this an edge dev tools problem? Do you see the update in Chrome dev tools?

Comment: I did not see it in Chrome developer tools either. It seemed a problem in the sense that I would expect the Network tab to show any network activity in the form of a new event added to the list in the Network pane. I'm learning that a web socket can be listed and is continuously running.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to use edge dev tools, but in Chrome dev tools, you can see that there's a websocket opened at

wss://wsjstream.wsj.net/BG2/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=0e136e61-8b97-4008-af9c-b8151887ca9f%3A&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22mainhub%22%7D%5D&tid=7

Sending JSON frames including content like:

```
{"h":{"t":"/quotes/zigman/627449/realtime","a":"broadcast","s":"SBK","n":2862885223},"b":{"z":"/Date(1538070813000)/","t":"627449","l":26510.42,"v":113513235,"c":125.14,"y":"normal","e":-4,"b":null,"a":null,"em":0}}
```

[image: Dev tools]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I looked at the activity of that web socket in Chrome developer tools and did see the JSON frames, but oddly, there are empty strings "" where I would expect the updated quote to be. If there was a number there, I would have to learn how a program can run a web socket. I have only used WinINet to download http resources from web servers.

Comment: @StevenBrown At Stack Overflow we would like to know if your question as asked was answered so it can be helpful to others. If you have further questions on how to use WebSockets, you should create new questions after you have [read up on it](https://pushfyi.com/blog/an-introduction-to-websockets-beginners-guide/) and played around. Is there anything else you don't understand about looking up where the data is coming from in dev tools?

Comment: Thanks for the link. To learn more about web sockets, I downloaded a demo app from https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-websockets. I'll be sure to ask if further questions about developer tools arise.

Answer (score 0):

You said ," I want to see the URL, headers, and response of that request."

Are you talking about this which you can see in an image below?

[image]

[image]

Let us know, If you are looking for anything else. We will try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: Thank you. I've been able to view responses to http requests, but was not aware of web sockets.